# How to manage tagged questions in class diagram

Tags: database-design, many-to-many, uml, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

If I have a clone of a Stackoverflow application, I would have two classes: `Question` and `Tag` class, and a relationship between them to be many-to-many.

How would I model this in class diagram? Will I create a class between them?

Note: I'm trying to apply DDD so `Question` and `Tag` would be entities

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you're trying to apply DDD then don't just design a data model. Focus on behaviors and invariants. Adding, removing tags and what happens should happen to old questions when tags changes over time (renamed, description updated, tag disabled/archived/prohibited, etc.). This is what's going to lead you to the proper design: considering aggregation vs composition and values vs entities.

Answer (score 1):

All depends on what you want to show. Here I propose several ways including bad/incomplete ones explaining their goal/context, rather than to just propose one solution as you can see in the answer of similar question.

> Will I create a class between them?

If the question is about UML (class diagram) out of an implementation using Sql or any other database, then the answer is *no*.

In this context I do not see a reason to have a class-association too, so if you have the classes *Question* and *Tag* and a relation there is just

[image]

Not sure anyway each tag knows the questions using it, so probably it is just

[image]

---

But if you want to show the implementation using an intermediate table to memorize all the couples then

[image]

because the table is unique the attribute *table* can be defined at the class level (*static*), but it is also possible to not have these attributes *table* and probably that table is a singleton

[image]

But without additional constraint these two previous ways allow to have for instance a Question not associated with a Tag in the Table. To not have to add constraints better to do

[image]

An intermediate way is to use a class-association

[image]

but that way partially hides the implementation, and a way to implement the class association is the previous solution. So better to use one of the first 2 ways completely hiding the implementation or the solution with the 4 classes fully showing the implementation.